# Bundling css even if using @import

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I'm developing an application in C# and Asp.Net MVC. I have various css files one called `base.css` which I then import into other css files using `@import` rule as:

```
@import url('base.css');
```

Then I bundle my css files to minimise them as:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css"));
                  ... more css files
```

So my question is do I have to bundle `base.css` even if I'm importing it into a different css? Because if I don't bunble it then the styling doesn't work as required.

Comment: This probably isn't the answer you want to hear but why not just include `base.css` in your bundle. Import is known to cause page speed issues. Once bundled you can remove the `@import`

Comment: @AshleyMedway That' probably the route I'm going to go down, but I was just wondering why it doesn't work and from `@krillgar` answer it makes sense

Comment: Yeah that's basically the answer, I'd add that you could get it to "work" by having your import file in the "same" location (virtual) as your bundle or by using an absolute url

Comment: If you update your import rule to: `@import url('/Content/base.css');` then it will continue to work once the other styles are bundled, but it is probably better to remove the rule altogether and include it in your bundle - that way you can take advantage of the other optimisations within the bundling service (minification, etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the MVC Bundler creates an entirely new file in a potentially different location (see the full path in your bundle name), the location of those `import` statements now becomes inaccurate.

What you can do instead is to create a separate CSS file (or static declaration on your `_Layout` page that includes only those `import` statements), and include that outside of any bundle.